# Windows 10 network issues

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

Since I've upgraded from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10, my connection randomly lags. In a minute I'm receiving 13Mb by wifi, in the next I only get 1Mb or less. I've switched off the shared updates and reinstalled wifi drivers, but the problem persists. Any ideas?

Comment: The drivers you re-installed are they for Windows 10 ? Download the driver for windows 10 from wireless adapter manufacturer

Comment: The wireless adaptar is a Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 and the only drivers I found on the Intel website were for Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to:

Control Panel > Device Manger > Networks adapter > Right click on Wireless LAN network > Proprieties > Advanced

Now make sure your options like this

- Bandwidth capability > 11b/g or 11b/g/n
- Fragmentation Threshold > 2346
- Power Output > 100%
- 802.11n > Auto "NOT MIXED"
- Antenna Diversity > Auto
- Compatibility Mode > Higher Performance
- ARB Ofloud > Enable
- BSS > Auto

Comment: My Windows is in Portuguese and I couldn't find all those options, but the ones I could were just like you suggested.

Comment: That's the default setting for the WiFi card :) if they are correct and you still have the same issues just download a program called DriverBooster and make it Update your driver

Comment: I already tried DriverBooster and it says it's all up to date. The problem started a week after installing Windows 10 and it goes on for a week now. I have other WIndows 10 computer at home and it works fine, and they have roughly the same background programs running.

Comment: That's all what I know :) I have a laptop with win 8.1 have a problem like this one and solve it in the same way..

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll look for other possible fixes :)

Comment: I had very similar problems.  The makers of my laptop have not released Windows 10 drivers yet.  But according to Device Manager, the installed Windows 8.1 drivers are working properly without any errors.  Still, my wireless would get disconnected at least a few times every hour.  Then I got an ethernet cable and connected it, and everything has been running perfectly since then.  So, my guess is that the problem is with the wireless driver, and I just have to wait until the Windows 10 version is released.  You might be in the same boat as me.

Comment: I guess I'll have to try that, time to buy a long ethernet cable, since I can't move the modem. Hopefully new drivers will come. I just fear that, since the computer is almost 4 years old, they won't release any. Thanks for your input too!